# Plotting system of (implicit) equations in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

First off, I'm new to python and matplotlib. I need to plot several systems of implicit equations in one figure.

The equations are in form of:

```
3x+2y=1
```

Is there an easy way to plot these, other than first making the equations explicit (i.e. `y=...`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`contour()`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.contour) to do implicit plots in two space dimensions:

```
x = numpy.linspace(-2., 2.)
y = numpy.linspace(-2., 2.)[:, None]
contour(x, y.ravel(), 3*x + 2*y, [1])
```

In 3 dimensions, I suggest using [Mayavi](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/docs/development/html/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#enthought.mayavi.mlab.contour3d) instead of matplotlib.

Comment: Hm.. This seems to generate a different graph than the graph for y=(1-3x)/2 which should be the same. Any ideas why?

Comment: @mewoshh: Could you show your exact code, please?  It should be something like `contour(x.ravel(), y, y-(1-3*x)/2, [0])`.  And the graph should be the same as for the code above.

Comment: It is the same as `contour(x.ravel(), y, y-(1-3*x)/2, [0])`. The problem is that this is not the same as the factual graph of `y=(1-3x)/2`. Compare this with `x=np.arange(-6,6,0.01); y=(1-3*x)/2; plot(x,y)`.

Comment: @mewoshh: You are right, confused rows and columns!  Will be corrected in a second...

Comment: It plotted the transposed graph.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 7):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Note the order of y,x.
y,x=np.ogrid[-5:5:100j,-5:5:100j]
plt.contour(x.ravel(),y.ravel(),3*x+2*y,[1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: And for three space dimensions, I suggest using [Mayavi](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/docs/development/html/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#enthought.mayavi.mlab.contour3d) instead.  (I'll delete my answer, because yours has a picture :)

Comment: @Sven Marnach: I like your solution because it uses less memory. Perhaps undelete it?

Comment: OK, on your special request :)

Comment: Thanks both of you. One thing seems to be wrong however; for instance, 3x+2y=1 & 3x+4y=5 should intercept at (-1,2). MPL however gives med an intersection point of (2,-1). What's wrong?

Comment: To clarify - the above graph is not the same as the graph for y=(1-3x)/2 (the explicit version of 3x+2y=1), hence the intersection points are wrong as a result of this. This is the main problem though - your solution doesn't give the correct graph.

Comment: @mewoshh: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I like Sven's answer, but just want correct mine for my own sanity.